# Calculating monthly fund returns

Tags: r

```
ln_f5 <- log(Fund_5, base = exp(1))
n <- nrow(Date)
ln_returns_f5 <- ((ln_f5[2:(n+1), 1] - ln_f5[1:n, 1])/ln_f5[1:n, 1])
```

Here, I have narrowed my sample of funds to one fund and taken logs (ln_f5).

I then try and calculate the returns based on the formula above I found online.

When I view the results of ln_returns_f5, there should be no cell return entry for day n (as there is no results for n-1).

Instead, the return for day n+1 is in the cell for day n.

How would I effectively move all the cell results one period forward so my return entry for n would be blank?

Many Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `dplyr`'s `lead()` and `lag()` function. Those probably help you out.

Comment: I am trying to create an (nx1) vector of returns. I am not sure whether I am using this function correctly but it seems to provide a single result instead of a vector of returns. Thanks Martin.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and an example of your desired output based on that data?

Comment: I do apologize I not be clearly stating what I want to achieve as I am new to R.  ```{r}
 y = c(8,10,12,14,16,18)
``` For example if I had this vector of returns. Each result represents the year from 2010 - 2015. The return based upon the value of 8 should be zero becasue i dont have a value for 2009. In R currently, it is putting (10-8)/8 in the first cell instead of zero.

Comment: I hope this helps and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`

```r
y <- c(8,10,12,14,16,18)

my_return <- ifelse(is.na((y-lag(y))/lag(y)), 0, (y-lag(y))/lag(y))
```

which returns

```r
[1] 0.0000000 0.2500000 0.2000000 0.1666667 0.1428571 0.1250000
```

You can skip the whole `ifelse(is.na())` part if you are fine with an `NA` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how you have structured the data and what return you desire to calculate, but perhaps this can serve as inspiration:

```
library(data.table)
# For long data:
dt_long<-ggplot2::economics_long
setDT(dt_long)[order(date),return:=(value/shift(value,n=1, type = 'lag')-1)*100,by=variable]

# For wide data
dt<-ggplot2::economics
setDT(dt)
return_columns<-names(dt[,-"date"])
dt[,paste("return_",return_columns):=lapply(.SD,function(x){(x/shift(x,n=1, type = 'lag')-1)*100}),.SDcols=return_columns]
```